# Using str_match in R to check for numbers seperated by "_"

Tags: r, dataframe, stringr

I am trying to use a code in R that I found online. It has a dataframe `model_data_frame` as

```
model_data_frame
          Matchup Win
1  2012_1140_1233   1
2  2012_1290_1443   0
3  2012_1143_1378   0
4  2012_1249_1436   0
```

The person then set

```
pattern <- "[A-Z]_([0-9]{3})_([0-9]{3})"
```

and then

```
teamIDs <- as.data.frame(str_match(model_data_frame$Matchup, pattern))
teamIDs <- teamIDs[ , c(2,3)]
```

I'm guessing the result for `teamIDs` should look something like

```
teamIDs
    V1   V2  
1  1140 1233
2  1290 1443 
3  1143 1378 
4  1249 1436
```

instead it looks like

```
 teamIDs
    V1   V2  
1  <NA> <NA>
2  <NA> <NA> 
3  <NA> <NA> 
4  <NA> <NA>
```

I'm guessing its because `pattern <- "[A-Z]_([0-9]{3})_([0-9]{3})"` is wrong. What should I change it to?

Comment: Change it to `\\d{4}_(\\d{4})_(\\d{4})`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way of doing this than relying on regex.
Use `strsplit`.

```
df <- read.table("clipboard", header = T)
teamIDs <- t(as.data.frame(strsplit(as.character(df$Matchup),"_")))[,2:3]
```